# Editing python file library and packges with VB.NET

Tags: python, vb.net, file, io, stream

I have some python files and I want to change their headers:

```
import os
import math
```

I need to add the directories before the import like:

```
from com.firebox import os
from com.fireboxtraining import math
```

(I have the directorylist)

I know how to read with stream readers. somebody helped here how to get the list. But now i want to paste the directory or package. What to do then?

Comment: vb.net seems like the wrong tool here. Much easier with, say, Python!

Answer (score 1):

Python files are just regular files, which you can read like you would any text file.
What you need to do is open the file, check for the lines containing imports, alter those lines, and write all that to a new file.
To get you started, here is a mockup with parts that are left out for you to figure out:

```vbs
Dim file As System.IO.File
Dim reader as System.IO.StreamReader
Dim line As String
reader = file.OpenText("ThePythonFile.py")

'open a new file for writing the results here

While reader.Peek <> -1
   'get lines one by one
   line = reader.ReadLine()

   'check to see if it has import. this is just an example, 
   'you should have a more complicated check here, like regex
   If line.Contains("import") Then
       'alter the line as you wish
   End If

   'Write the line to the new file

End While
reader.Close()

'close the second file
'If you want, you can replace the old file with the new one here
```

Comment: but I have to add different directory in from according to imported class. so I have to read also all the imported class. then I have to add the corresponding directory(provided from a list) before the import. any suggestion? @Lawrence

Comment: Well, the code I provided enables you to do that. When you have the `import` line in `line` variable, you can find the appropriate module and append the corresponding directory from your list. You can use `Contains()` function or `Regex` to check for a module being imported in that line. You can do whatever you want with it then.